# JSON Data not appearing in listview

Tags: android

I have been trying to populate a ListView of mine with JSON data from a few URLs. The problem is, it is not appearing in the ListView, despite the fact that my LogCat clearly showing that it has received the data. Have a look at my code below.

**XML ListView:**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView

    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ListView Activity:**

```
public ListView mListView;

private static final String EventNamesURL = 
"http://eventsweb23.000webhostapp.com/JSON/EventNames.json";
private static final String EventDatesURL = 
"http://eventsweb23.000webhostapp.com/JSON/EventDates.json";
private static final String EventPlacesURL = 
"http://eventsweb23.000webhostapp.com/JSON/codebeautify.json";
private static final String EventTimesURL = 
"http://eventsweb23.000webhostapp.com/JSON/EventTimes.json";
private static final String EventURLs = 
"http://eventsweb23.000webhostapp.com/JSON/EventURLs.json";
private static final String EventImagesURL = 
"http://eventsweb23.000webhostapp.com/JSON/EventImages.json";

ArrayList<String> NameList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> DatesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> PlacesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> TimesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> URLList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ImagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> EventList = new ArrayList<>();

public String title;
public String place;
public String imageUrl;
public String time;
public String date;
public String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

    Context context = this;
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    EventsAdapter adapter = new EventsAdapter(context, EventList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    new FetchNameDataTask().execute(EventNamesURL);
    new FetchDateDataTask().execute(EventDatesURL);
    new FetchPlaceDataTask().execute(EventPlacesURL);
    new  FetchTimeDataTask().execute(EventTimesURL);
    new FetchURLDataTask().execute(EventURLs);
    new FetchImageDataTask().execute(EventImagesURL);


    setList();

    }





//Thread for fetching event names
public class FetchNameDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //getCookieUsingCookieHandler();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.i("App", "Data received: " + result);

            } else
                result = "Failed to fetch data";

            return result;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dataFetched) {
        //parse the JSON data and then display
        parseJSONEvents(dataFetched);
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) 
    throws IOException, JSONException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            //responseStrBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    public void parseJSONEvents(String data) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

            int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                //listviewActivity listviewActivity1 = new 
            listviewActivity();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                title = jsonChildNode.getString("event_name");
                //NameList.add(listviewActivity.title);
                EventList.add(title);

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("App", "Error parsing data: " + e.getMessage());

        }

    }


}

//Thread for fetching event dates
private class FetchDateDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //getCookieUsingCookieHandler();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.i("App", "Data received: " + result);

            } else
                result = "Failed to fetch data";

            return result;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dataFetched) {
        //parse the JSON data and then display
        parseJSONEvents(dataFetched);
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) 
    throws IOException, JSONException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            //responseStrBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    private void parseJSONEvents(String data) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

            int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                //listviewActivity listviewActivity2 = new 
            listviewActivity();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                date = jsonChildNode.getString("event_date");
                //DatesList.add(listviewActivity.date);
                EventList.add(date);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("App", "Error parsing data: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }

}

//Thread for fetching event places
private class FetchPlaceDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //getCookieUsingCookieHandler();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.i("App", "Data received: " + result);

            } else
                result = "Failed to fetch data";

            return result;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dataFetched) {
        //parse the JSON data and then display
        parseJSONEvents(dataFetched);
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) 
    throws IOException, JSONException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            //responseStrBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    private void parseJSONEvents(String data) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

            int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                //listviewActivity listviewActivity3 = new listviewActivity();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                place = jsonChildNode.getString("event_place");
                //PlacesList.add(listviewActivity.place);
                EventList.add(place);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("App", "Error parsing data: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}

//Thread for fetching event times
private class FetchTimeDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //getCookieUsingCookieHandler();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.i("App", "Data received: " + result);

            } else
                result = "Failed to fetch data";

            return result;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dataFetched) {
        //parse the JSON data and then display
        parseJSONEvents(dataFetched);
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) 
    throws IOException, JSONException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            //responseStrBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    private void parseJSONEvents(String data) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

            int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                //listviewActivity listviewActivity4 = new 
            listviewActivity();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                time = jsonChildNode.getString("event_time");
                //TimesList.add(listviewActivity.time);
                EventList.add(time);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("App", "Error parsing data: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}

//Thread for fetching event URLs
private class FetchURLDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //getCookieUsingCookieHandler();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.i("App", "Data received: " + result);

            } else
                result = "Failed to fetch data";

            return result;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dataFetched) {
        //parse the JSON data and then display
        parseJSONEvents(dataFetched);
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) 
    throws IOException, JSONException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            //responseStrBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    private void parseJSONEvents(String data) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

            int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                //listviewActivity listviewActivity5 = new 
            listviewActivity();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                url = jsonChildNode.getString("event_url");
                //URLList.add(listviewActivity.url);
                EventList.add(url);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("App", "Error parsing data: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}

//Thread for fecthing event image URLs
private class FetchImageDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //getCookieUsingCookieHandler();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.i("App", "Data received: " + result);

            } else
                result = "Failed to fetch data";

            return result;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dataFetched) {
        //parse the JSON data and then display
        parseJSONEvents(dataFetched);
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) 
    throws IOException, JSONException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            //responseStrBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    private void parseJSONEvents(String data) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

            int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                //listviewActivity listviewActivity6 = new 
            listviewActivity();
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                imageUrl = jsonChildNode.getString("img_url");
                //ImagesList.add(listviewActivity.imageUrl);
                EventList.add(imageUrl);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("App", "Error parsing data: " + e.getMessage());

        }


    }
}

public ArrayList getArrayList(){
    return EventList;
}

public void setList() {

    //final ArrayList<listviewActivity> List =  getArrayList();

    String[] listItems = new String[EventList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < EventList.size(); i++) {
        EventList.get(i);
        listItems[i] = title;
    }



    final Context context = this;
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
      position, long id) {

            //1
            EventList.get(position);

            //2
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(context, event_detail.class);

            //3
            detailIntent.putExtra("title", title);
            detailIntent.putExtra("url", url);

            //4
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }

    });
```

I pretty much used the same code for each of the Async Tasks, the only difference, being the URLs to fetch Data from. Each Async Tasks successfully fetches the JSON From its URL and displays it on the LogCat.

**ListView Adapter:**

```
public class EventsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

LayoutInflater minflater;
Context mcontext;
ArrayList<String> mDataSource;



public EventsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items){
    mcontext = context;
    mDataSource = items;
    minflater = (LayoutInflater) 
mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDataSource.get(position);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Get view for row item
    View rowView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_event, parent, 
false);

    //Get the title element
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_title);

    //Get the date element
    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_date);

    //Get the time element
    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_time);

    //Get the time element
    TextView placeTextView = (TextView) 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_place);

    //Get the thumbnail element
    ImageView thumbnailImageView = (ImageView) 
rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_thumbnail);

    //1
    listviewActivity listviewActivity = (listviewActivity) 
getItem(position);

    //2
    titleTextView.setText(listviewActivity.title);
    dateTextView.setText(listviewActivity.date);
    timeTextView.setText(listviewActivity.time);
    placeTextView.setText(listviewActivity.place);

    //3

Picasso.with(mcontext)
.load(listviewActivity.imageUrl)
.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.resize(250,250).centerCrop().into(thumbnailImageView);

return rowView;
  }
}
```

I also used a second XML Layout which shall contain the JSON data from the URLs which I inflated in the ListView Activity.

**Here it is:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/event_list_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/recipe_list_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/event_list_thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/event_list_thumbnail">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="Event Name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_list_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Date"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_list_date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Time"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_list_time"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Place"
        />

   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Like I said earlier, **I do not have a problem retrieving the JSON Data**. My problem is populating the data into the ListView. If anyone can explain to me why my data is not appearing and what I can do to solve it, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly you setting adapter ? In `listviewActivity()` method ? And there

Comment: Hello @ADM, if you scroll down on my ListView Activity code, you will find that I set my adapter in the OnCreate() method.

Comment: You posted a lots of code . Anyway i see 6 `AsyncTask` why? In which one you are setting list ?

Comment: Yes, I used a php to retrieve the code from my DataBase but it wasn't outputting the JSON as a single object but as multiple JSON arrays, and Android studio failed to parse it so I had to separate the JSON arrays and use different Async Tasks to fetch data from each of them

Comment: So you are saying that You are merging each AsyncTask response to build the listView data ? am i right ?

Comment: Yes, you are indeed correct, data retrieved from each of the Async Tasks is assigned to each of the ListView Activity's String Variables, which my ListView Adapter is meant to handle.

Comment: each of the ListView ? You have only one `ListView` there in code .Isn't it

Comment: No you misunderstand, the data is assigned to string variables in the ListView Activity, which are all to be placed in that one listview.

Comment: you are missing `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` . And this is not gonna work . 6 Api calls for one response . You have to come up with better solution.Think what if a single APi will fail due to `ConnectionTimeOut`?

Comment: @ADM if you look just below the 'setListAdapter()' method, you will find that I did use 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()'

Comment: Where in `onCreate()`?

Comment: @ADM scroll down abit on my ListView activity code and you will find it just below `mListView.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: First suggestion change the server query if you can to return your all event details(name,time,image...etc) in single api call.

Comment: Add listviewactivity code.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH The code is there. Just scroll through it above and have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single json API to fetch your all event data.
You also declared many arraylist: `NameList ,DatesList` , but you have commented the statement where you add item to list. Like this one

```
 //DatesList.add(listviewActivity.date);
```

The solution i found is

```
 public void parseJSONEvents(String data) {

    try {
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(data);

        int jsonArrLength = jsonMainNode.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
            //listviewActivity listviewActivity1 = new 
        listviewActivity();
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            title = jsonChildNode.getString("event_name");
            //NameList.add(listviewActivity.title);
            EventList.add(title);

        }
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("App", "Error parsing data: " + e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `for` loop in `parseJSONEvents` method.

comment all these code once like:

```
 /*   listviewActivity listviewActivity = (listviewActivity) 
    getItem(position);

    //2
    titleTextView.setText(listviewActivity.title);
    dateTextView.setText(listviewActivity.date);
    timeTextView.setText(listviewActivity.time);
    placeTextView.setText(listviewActivity.place);

    //3

Picasso.with(mcontext)
.load(listviewActivity.imageUrl)
.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.resize(250,250).centerCrop().into(thumbnailImageView); */
```

and add this line

```
titleTextView.setText(mDataSource.get(position));
```

Comment: I see, but why is it that I should call that method in the loops, when I have already called it in the `onCreate()` method? Is there a difference?

Comment: Yes I did comment on them because before I uploaded this code, I tried to use those Array Lists to store the data and call on those Array Lists in a different class, but to do that, they had to be declared as static and I still ended up having the same problem.

Comment: you have to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); AFTER for loop, to tell your adapter that your array items has been changed so you adapter will set the new data from array, you called it in onCreate but that time no data available in array so it wont work, you have to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); once you array list items has been changed or added or deleted.

Comment: I just implemented your code but a `Java.lang.ClassException` has now been thrown on my ListViewAdapter at `listviewActivity listviewActivity = (listviewActivity) 
getItem(position)`. Any reason for this?

Comment: i edited my answer check,use it once and tell me what output you are seeing after run

Comment: It works! I was successfully able to see the JSON data. However, each of the elements exists as an item instead of how Listing the title, name, date, place and time as one list item. Do I have to use `titleTextView.setText(mDataSource.get(position))` for all the other TextViews to solve this?

Comment: Yes there is better way to do it, but first tell me, are you want to show these :title, place, image, time, date, url in a single list item? if yes, then you have to use single API to get title, place, imageUrl, time, date for all event.

Comment: ,I see. So what do you suggest? That I use a single Async Task to get the JSON data from all the URLs?

Comment: Yes use single Async Task but not for all URLs you have to merge response of all url, USE ONLY SINGLE API (URL)